# External variable and scoping inside jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code below which supposed to run `test()` every time the window is resized.

```
var i = 0;
var test = (function() {
    console.log(i++);
})();

$(window).resize(function() {
    test();
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/NEUdA/

However, I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` because `test()` is not available within resize.

Can someone help to explain why? And what is the workaround to have **(1) a self-executing function** and **(2) be able to call it within `resize`**?

Comment: `test` IS available inside `resize`, it's just that you set it equal to undefined.

Comment: @Kevin but how come it doesn't execute either?

Comment: you should be getting 1 log in your console currently, and then an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick, though it is not really any more convienent than just calling the function right after the declaration:

```
var i = 0;
var test = (function test() {
    console.log(i++);
    return test;
})();

$(window).resize(function() {
    test();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do this:

```
var test = function() {
    console.log(i++);
};
```

instead of this:

```
var test = (function() {
    console.log(i++);
})();
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NEUdA/1/

The second form will invoke the function on the spot, and because it doesn't have a return statement, it will return undefined, so test will be undefined.

Why do you want test to be self-executing?

Comment: Self-executing is required as a way to initialize that function. I could do `test();` right after but seem unclean

Comment: If you really have to execute the function, return another function from it that will be assigned to the test variable. That returned function will get called on window.resize. Even better, do something similar to the module pattern, and add the function that needs to be called on resize to a variable. http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html